Converting Pybtex back to .bib file
I am trying to automate some tasks on .bib files (filter out some entries, replace conference names by acronyms, etc.). This works out, but I am not able to reconvert to BibliographyData back to a .bib file.
as an example, when I run
from pybtex.database import BibliographyData, Entry
bib_data = BibliographyData({
     'article-minimal': Entry('article', [
         ('author', 'L[eslie] B. Lamport'),
         ('title', 'The Gnats and Gnus Document Preparation System'),
         ('journal', "G-Animal's Journal"),
         ('year', '1986'),
     ]),
 })
print(bib_data.to_string('bibtex'))

I get the error message
plugin pybtex.database.output.bibtex not found

This is exactly the example documented on https://docs.pybtex.org/api/parsing.html#pybtex.database.BibliographyData.to_file, but I cannot find any solution to this issue.
Thank you.
